Problem with download dataset from Open images-v7 with fiftyOne
I'm trying to download the Open Images V7 dataset using FiftyOne, but I've run into a strange issue. When I import FiftyOne, everything seems fine. However, when I run my code, I can't specify the target folder for the dataset. It still shows: "Downloading split 'train' to 'C:\Users\Lenovo\fiftyone\open-images-v7\train' if necessary." After downloading, I get the following error:
Dataset info written to 'C:\Users\Lenovo\fiftyone\open-images-v7\info.json'
Loading 'open-images-v7' split 'train'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\MachineLearning\YOLOv8_tutorial\code\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.makedirs(dataset_dir)
  File "E:\Anaconda\anaconda3\envs\fiftyOne\lib\site-packages\fiftyone\zoo\datasets\__init__.py", line 429, in load_zoo_dataset
    dataset_importer, _ = foud.build_dataset_importer(
TypeError: fiftyone.utils.data.importers.build_dataset_importer() got multiple values for keyword argument 'dataset_dir'.


Here's the code snippet I'm using. How to understand why this error is occurring and fix it then?
import fiftyone as fo
import fiftyone.zoo as foz

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset(
        "open-images-v7",
        split="train",
        label_types=["detections"],
        classes=["Alpaca"],
        max_samples=10,
        dataset_dir="D:\\MachineLearning\\YOLOv8_tutorial\\images_alpaca"
    )


I am confused, why I you specifying the dataset_dir for loading data from the Zoo?

You just need to remove the dataset_dir and export the dataset after it is loaded.
Code example:
dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset(
        "open-images-v7",
        split="train",
        label_types=["detections"],
        classes=["Alpaca"],
        max_samples=10
    )

export_path = "./my_dataset/"
dataset.export(
    export_dir=export_path,
    dataset_type=fo.types.YOLOv5Dataset,  
)

